# How can I change focus without firing up the throttle?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I can use <kbd>tab</kbd> to change between foci, e.g. if my focus is Kerbin and I hit tab, focus shifts to the Mun. However to go back without cycling through every celestial object requires pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> +<kbd>tab</kbd>, which fires the throttle, which alters my course. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Change your throttle bindings! :P

Comment: @pixel I am not sure this is even possible!

Comment: Me either to be honest, it would make sense it is because the wiki mentions "default" bindings, but I've never actually looked through any of the menus in KSP

Comment: Have you tried minimizing the nav ball?

Comment: @MBraedley Good plan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found two potential solutions to this:

**Minimize the Nav Ball** - this prevents shift from activating the thrusters

**Double-click to focus** - If you can see an object, you can double click to focus on it.

Answer (score 3):

Use right shift instead of left shift.  Left shift is throttle; right shift is not bound in the game and can be used.

Comment: Why did this get a downvote? Does it not work?

Answer (score 1):

The navball is disabled in map view by default and you cannot alter throttle while it is disabled.

But don't forget that liquid fuel tanks and engines can be disabled manually using their context menus. Might come in handy for other situations.

Answer (score 1):

Press the Backspace key while in Map mode.

Answer (score -2):

I have nothing to say about toggling through planets, but if you go to the Tracking Station and double-click a spacecraft, you will focus on that craft.

Comment: This doesn't add anything that isn't already in the other answer.